# AngularFire2 - Append to list child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to add an object to `/users/[userKey]/invitedTo` but `set` deletes the existing data, so does `update`.

What I want to end up with is something like this:

```
users
    -uniqueuserkey
        --name: Name
        --InvitedTo
            ---eventuniquekey1
                ----eventname: event name 1
                ----etc
            ---eventuniquekey2
                ----eventname: event name 2
                ----etc
```

-

```
// this.event.push(eventObj);
this.event.push(eventObj).then((item) => {
  if (item) {
    const itemKey = item.key;
    for (const key in guests) {
      if (guests.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        const invitedObj = {};
        const invitedTo = this.db.object(`/users/${key}/invitedTo`);
        invitedObj[itemKey] = eventObj;
        invitedTo.set( { invitedObj } );

      }
    }
  }
});
```

Update does exactly what I need, but it also deletes existing value:

```
    for (const key in guests) {
      if (guests.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const invitedObj = {};
        invitedObj[itemKey] = eventObj;
        this.users.update(key, { invitedTo: invitedObj });
      }
    }
```

Should I just get the existing data and add to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an object, you (usually) should use the `push` method instead of `set` or `update`:

```
const invitedTo = this.db.list(`/users/${key}/invitedTo`);
invitedTo.push(eventObj);
```

That way, Firebase will create a unique key and add it to the `invitedTo` node.

If you want to set the key yourself, then you could use the `update` method like this:

```
const invitedTo = this.db.object(`/users/${key}/invitedTo/${itemKey}`);
invitedTo.update(eventObj);
```